# WopiFrame - how to set the URL behind the Exit menu?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

In a document library in SP2013 on-premise we store RMS protected documents. We link to those documents from the welcome page, using the ?Web=1 url parameter so they open in the word web app. So far so nice. But this word view has the "office ribbon" UI and there is the Exit button. And this brings the user to the actual document library where the file is stored. But it should bring the user back to the Welcome page (the app where hes is coming from).

I learned that I could create the WopiFrame.aspx/WopiFrame2.aspx url myself and include an &action=embedview to not have the office UI (i. E. to load in an iframe). But this embedview refuses to show RMS documents! :-(

Question: Can I somehow specify where the "Exit" of an office web app redirects to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies to the rescue! The office web app seems to respect a cookie `WOPISessionContext`. Set its value to the URL you want to get back to and "Exit" will do as you wish!