# Wopiframe.aspx - SharePoint 2016 - Redirect user to correct location

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, owa

This issue has been reported many times before but none of the work around works for me.

Scenario : User opens a document in office web apps from a document set. When the user want to go back and click on the link (marked as yellow in picture below) in OWA, they got sent to wrong location.

[image]

Following are the articles explaining the problem and possible solutions but non of them worked for me.

[Redirect user when document closes in office web apps?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121875/redirect-user-when-document-closes-in-office-web-apps)

[WopiFrame - how to set the URL behind the Exit menu?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121939/wopiframe-how-to-set-the-url-behind-the-exit-menu/124914)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_web_apps_server_2013_support_blog/2014/01/22/office-web-apps-2013-office-web-apps-redirect-to-incorrect-sharepoint-library/

Any more suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to Office Online Server?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Upgraded already to Office Online server. Strange thing is that it works with SharePoint 2013 but not with SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Maddy's comment. I just completed a SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 upgrade. The Office Documents in the WOPIframe contain the wrong URL. All other Search results are good. This worked fine in 2013. My Search Crawlers are configured identically between 2013 and 2016. Seems the server mappings are being ignored, only for the WOPIframe results.

I've got a support call into Microsoft on this issue. I'll update again if they have a fix.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Got any fix for this issue?